# Отношение управляемого объекта и игры в ООП

Tags: javascript, ооп, разработка-игр

Не совсем понятно как реализовать ход черепашки в парадигме ООП на JS. На кнопке следующий код: `onClick="turtle.move()`. Если `turtle.rotate()` ещё как-то черепашка может осилить сама, то тут нужно взаимодействовать с суровой реальностью, но как -- до конца не понимаю.

Насколько я понял, архитектура любой игры, сделанной в ООП стиле, должна сводится к композиции всех классов в одном большом классе Game. Тогда как должен примерно выглядеть интерфейс взаимодействия пользователя с игрой (лучше даже сказать интерфейса с логикой)? Напрашивается, что через вызов методов объекта game. То есть на кнопке должен быть некий метод `game.turtle.move()`, который взаимодействует с экземпляром `game.board` класса Board, который в свою очередь взаимодействует с экземплярами `game.board.fields` класса Field?

Прилагаю исходники: [https://git.sr.ht/~liltechdude/cherepashka-js/tree/master/item/script.js](https://git.sr.ht/%7Eliltechdude/cherepashka-js/tree/master/item/script.js)

Comment: что-то как то сомнительно что turtle содержит game а не наоборот

Comment: @teran У меня в исходниках или в вопросе несоответствие?

Comment: Зря правки откатили. А с чем конкретно вы не согласны?

Comment: @Kromster как минимум, что game не содержит turtle, если я с вами про одно и то же

Comment: Поменьше разных вложенных классов и побольше здравого смысла. По сути, объект (экземпляр класса) game вам нужен лишь для хранения всех данных, относящихся к конкретной игре. Вот и действуйте в данном направлении

Comment: _«архитектура любой игры, сделанной в ООП стиле, должна сводится к композиции всех классов в одном большом классе Game»_ - это неверно. Начни с самых основ, таких как различие между классом и экземпляром объекта. Далее, рекомендую ознакомиться с понятиями интерфейса (абстрактного класса) и агрегации. Это "далее" объяснит, как не пихать все в один жирный объект, при этом сохраняя связность сущностей. **p.s.:** по ссылке не ходил, т.к. вопросы здесь должны включать в себе (а не по ссылкам) все необходимое для раскрытия их сути. По той же причине, голосую за закрытие.

Comment: _«Тогда как должен примерно выглядеть интерфейс взаимодействия пользователя с игрой (лучше даже сказать интерфейса с логикой)? Напрашивается, что через вызов методов объекта game.»_ - верный вывод. Но почему-то, совершенно неверная (пусть даже гипотетическая) реализация: _«То есть на кнопке должен быть некий метод `game.turtle.move()`»_ - разве это вызов метода объекта `game`? Нет, это вызов метода объекта `turtle`! Почему тут иерархия ответственности не соблюдается, где делегирование - это то, о чем следует задуматься, внимательно посмотрев на верный вывод сделанный ранее.